# Sort array by index which specified in another array, best algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have a puzzle,

input

```
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    b = [1, 0, 3, 2];
```

output

```
['b', 'a', 'd', 'c']
```

My solution looks like this

```
function _sort(array, rules) {
  var i, len = rules.length, res = []

  if (array.length !== len) {
    return null; 
  }

  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    res[rules[i]] = array[i];
  }

  return res;
}
```

How can improve this algorithm ?

Comment: I don't understand your desired output

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    b = [1, 0, 3, 2];

function mySort(array, rules) {
    var sorted = [];

    for (var i=0; i< rules.length; i++) {
        sorted[rules[i]] = array[i];
    }

    return sorted;
}

mySort(a, b);

> ["b", "a", "d", "c"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you convert it to an array of arrays (`[[1,'a'],[0,'b'],[3,'c'],[2,'d']]`), which shouldn't be difficult, you can then call Javascript's built-in array.sort() method to sort it.

Answer (score 0):

Pure JS solution

```
var result = b.map(function(idx) { 
    return a[idx]; 
});
```

I would use some library like lodash or underscore

```
var result = _.map(b, function(idx) {
    return a[idx];
});
```

I would also note it is usually better to run a benchmark on a decently large data set. There is overhead when running a benchmark and as the data gets larger the less this overhead effects the results.